# Crux Page specific data by country?

Tags: pagespeed-insights, chrome-ux-report

Using Big Data to browse Crux, there is data on a country level for each origin. Page Speed Insights includes crux data for origin and also for specific pages.

Is there anyway to get a country breakdown for a single page through the Page Speed Insights API?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get a country breakdown through Page Speed Insights, either at an origin or at a page level.

However you can query the Chrome User Experience Report Big Data to get this information.

Please note that the field data shown in Page Speed Insights is a rolling 28 day average, updated daily, whereas the CRUX data is updated once per month so you would get differences.

Comment: The country data in Crux Big Data is only available by origin and not by page, correct?

Comment: It is actually available by page but only for pages with enough traffic. Try here for how to do it via the API https://web.dev/chrome-ux-report-api/#querying-url-data

Comment: Fruther down the page it mentions "other dimension", that is the bit you want for country breakdown, perhaps add it as another question specific to big data if you need help building the query.

Comment: Great! Thanks. 
Do you know if there is a good breakdown of when I would want to use pagespeedonline.googleapis.com
versus 
the crux data set in Big Query 
versus
chromeuxreport.googleapis.com ?

Comment: Ah unfortunately I think you can use Big Query to get country data but not URL specific, or you can use API to get URL specific, but not country data. (The country data referenced in "Additional dimensions" section in https://web.dev/chrome-ux-report-api/#querying-url-data seems to be in a "coming soon" section)

Comment: Looks like this is not supported currently: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chrome-ux-report/c/QRPEej9iY4M/m/oLK9wi71BAAJ

Comment: That is a shame, looks like you will have to wait until they introduce it I am afraid.